# $state.go not working properly. It works only first time, but not second time

Tags: angularjs

```
   vm.add=funtion(data) {
    causeService.add(data)
     .then(function(response){
      if(response.status = 'success'){
       $state.go('student.list');
        } else {
           //  
        }
   });
   }
```

I'm trying to add user. When this function is called first time it            works. When this function is called the second time it does not go to state. There is no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your promise is properly resolving in your causeService.add() method. If it does not resolve properly, the then method will never get called.

Also, your conditional only includes a single equals sign, which will always return true because it will return the value of response.status which you are setting to 'success'. See below:

```
if(response.status === 'success'){
    $state.go('student.list');
} else {
    // Do something if not successful
}
```

Comment: If (response.status === 'success') {.    ///comes here but not go to $state.go.   }

Comment: Do you have any resolves that the student.list state requires?

Comment: It might be that the particular resolve is failing. It will not throw an error, as displayed in this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/jEfQrRDQxImNDPIOH3Jm

Comment: Without seeing your state resolve code, I am not sure. It could be a number of things.

Comment: .state('student.list,{. url: '/list', controller:'controlllername'. ,controllerAs:  'cause', resolve: {. getCause: function(causeService){.return causeService.getCause();  }  }  })

Comment: I would check your causeService.getCause() method and make sure it is successfully resolving.

Comment: Whenever refresh browser ...listing comes

Comment: So its working properly.....problem in $state.go..second time does not hit student.list state